# View Contents of docx, pdf and text files obtained in Wireshark through PCAP file

Tags: packet-sniffers, packet-capture, wireshark-dissector

So, I have got a pcap file which I opened with Wireshark tool. Now, there are 4 files I can find through the HTTP filter:
1. A docx file
2. A pdf file
3. A txt file
4. PNG file

I extracted the PNG image file by the following :

Right click on the packet -> follow -> Using TCP -> Converted the file from ASCII to raw -> Searched for 'FFD8' and 'FFD9 and copy pasted the raw network text to HxD Hex editor and saved it as PNG.

I don't know how to view the contents of the rest. I am using a Windows 10 system. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark has the ability to export files from HTTP. On Macos & Windows, you can find this in the GUI as

`File > Export Objects > HTTP`

You can find more information about this in the Wireshark Guide at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html#ChIOExportObjectsDialog

You can also do this with tshark with `tshark --export-objects http,$dest_dir`. tshark.dev has an article on using this [here](https://tshark.dev/export/export_regular/).

Comment: I use windows 10. Sorry I didn't mention it in the main post. Edited now

Comment: @Benjamin It's the same menu path in Windows.

Comment: So there isn't any need for a Hex Editor? Because I need to view the contents of the docx and pdf files..